# Should Rails.env and Config.root work in 'rails console' model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Both objects seem to be nil inside of 'rails console'.

Why is that?

Actually now Rails works:

```
puts Rails.env
/path/to/my/project
```

but for config:

```
puts config.root

NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for #<Object:0x1001dd2a0>
    from (irb):8
```

Comment: This is not true for me. I'd ask for more information to help you debug, but I'm not sure what information to ask for. Are you sure you're in a Rails 3 application?

Comment: Rails.env and Rails.root works for me in the consoles of both Rails 3.0.1 and 2.3.10. As Matchu says, more debug information would be valuable.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no global `config` method. If you're copying this from your environment files in Rails 2, note that these are actually evaluated within a certain context.

To get to the `config` object from your console, try one of the following:

For Rails 3 and above:

```
Rails.application.config
```

For Rails 2.x:

```
Rails.configuration
```

If you need to get your project's root directory (not sure if this is actually what you're trying to accomplish), you can do the following in Rails 2 and above:

```
Rails.root
```